# How to skip over current element in a python list

Tags: python

How I can loop over a python list, add each item to another list except the current item:

```
list = [1,2,8,20,11]

for i,j in enumerate(list):
    print j[i+1:]
#this will only give [2,8,20,11] then [8,20,11],[20,11], [11]

#but I want something like [2,8,20,11], [1,8,20,11],[1,2,20,11]... etc.
#then 1,8,20,11
#then
```

Comment: Firstly don't name your variable as `list`

Comment: Even your incorrect code will not give the output you say it will. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) as:

```
lst = [1,2,8,20,11]
for i in xrange(len(lst)):
    print lst[:i]+lst[i+1:]

>>> [2, 8, 20, 11]
    [1, 8, 20, 11]
    [1, 2, 20, 11]
    [1, 2, 8, 11]
    [1, 2, 8, 20]
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're after `combinations`, eg:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> data = [1,2,8,20,11]
>>> list(combinations(data, 4))
[(1, 2, 8, 20), (1, 2, 8, 11), (1, 2, 20, 11), (1, 8, 20, 11), (2, 8, 20, 11)]
```